# Detecting Soft Keyboard Hidden State

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Want to `Toast` a text everytime when soft keyboard state changes from shown to hidden. Here I just want to `getText()` from `EditText` and everytime I click on `EditText` the soft Keyboard must open and after pressing back or return the text must be shown as `Toast`

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: use textChangeListener for your textView with a flag, when you are inside the textView and back is pressed, just toast your message!

Comment: @Saqib Can you please post some code. I will be very thankful for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no direct listener for keyboard state detection so you need some programatic implementation as below

```
private boolean wasKeyboardOpen = false;

try {
        activityMainView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                Rect r = new Rect();
                activityMainView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

                int heightDiff = activityMainView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);
                if (heightDiff > 100) {
                    wasKeyboardOpen = true;
                    // kEYBOARD IS OPEN

                } else {
                    if (wasKeyboardOpen) {
                        wasKeyboardOpen = false;
                        // Do your toast here

                    }
                    // kEYBOARD IS HIDDEN
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Boss. It Works for me. I was just missing a edge.

Comment: Please don't say boos dude just friends and accept the answer so that other can trust and use the answer.

Comment: Ya Sure, I have 1 more query to make it strong answer. My toast is popping up again and again after some time. Just want to know why this code is running again and again?

Comment: Because keyboard is hidden by default. This will call every time there is minor change in layout or view inside activity sizes because it is a globallayout listener. So for confirmation you need to manage boolean flag for last state. I just updata the answer.