# Detect soft-keyboard hide and hide the navigation buttons

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'm new to Java and Android, so the code i have i pasted together from the net. The goal is to create a simple web browser for one webpage. In that webpage, it's possible to edit text and such.

Main goal is to keep the browser **full screen**, so to keep away the android navigation buttons.

I tried to use this code but no success until know. 
[Detecting Soft Keyboard Hidden State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379541/detecting-soft-keyboard-hidden-state)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
    static int mAppHeight;
    static int currentOrientation = -1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //will hide the title
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); // hide the title bar
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); //enable full screen
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION|
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //make a webview object
        WebView webview=new WebView(this);

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION|
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
            }
        });

        // enable javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //show it through setcontentview()method
        setContentView(webview);

        webview.loadUrl("https://www.mypage.com");
    }


    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            hideSystemUI();
        }
    }

    private void hideSystemUI() {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
    }
}
```

Can someone help where to put the code from the link?

Thank you very much
Kind regards

EDIT:

I also tried this one, but i don't see the event get run when the soft keyboard shows or hides.: https://github.com/yshrsmz/KeyboardVisibilityEvent

Comment: Do you need the top status bar?

Comment: Hey, check this library (https://github.com/yshrsmz/KeyboardVisibilityEvent). I use it in few project and works great.

Comment: @AnupamBose: No i don't want anything but the webview on the screen.

Comment: Hi @Ikazuchi, I tried that one but couldn't get it to work. The events weren't executed somehow. Do you have an empty project activity with that event in it that you can sent?

Comment: Hey @socialb, I do not have any empty project with that, you can add a update to your question and i will check this out.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

            int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;

            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. This is the thing i tried. When i go on a page and enter a textedit, then the navigation buttons appear and don't go away.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest use this -

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activities. MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

In Activity onCreate use only this -

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
       setContentView(R.layout. activity_main);
```

AND REMOVE

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //will hide the title
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); // hide the title bar
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); //enable full screen
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION|
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: Hi @Anupam Bose, Thanks for the help. I tried to implement this in a new empty project. But every time i run it, it hangs on my phone. This before showing anything.